# How to shift every 'nth' character in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, encryption, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to modify a caesar shift program to shift not every character in an array but say every 5th character. Currently, characters can be input into a textarea which is then converted to an array and every character is shifted by whatever the shiftAmount(Key) is(as you'd expect). "abc" --by2--> "cde".

I tried `(int i=0; i<ptArray.length; i+=5)` which results in shifting every 5th character(including the 1st) it seems but also only counting those characters shifted thus not displaying any other characters in the array. Is there a modification I can make to the loop to achieve this? Ideally "abcdefghij" with every 5th letter shifted by 2 would display as "abcd**g**fghi**l**"

I'm trying to make a more secure cipher by shifting each character simultaneously by a different amount with a multi-integer key. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    public String shiftCipher (String p, int s) { //plaintext, shiftAmount
        //convert the input/plain string to an array of characters 
        char[] ptArray = p.toCharArray();
        //create array of characters to hold output/cipher string 
        char[] ctArray = new char[ptArray.length];

      //shift and put result in the ciphertext array
        for (int i=0; i<ptArray.length; i++) {
        int ascii = (int)ptArray[i];
        ascii = (ascii - 32 + s)%95 + 32;
        ctArray[i] = (char)ascii;
        }

          //convert ciphertext array to string
            String c = new String(ctArray);

            return c;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are making a Vigenère chiper for only some letters in the the message. Better to encrypt all letters and use a longer key.

`for(int i=0; i<ptArray.length; i+=5)` will step through every  5th letter in the array. (Don't forgett the assignment to the variable `i`).

Use only one array, unless you want an array with only the new letters. Overwrite the old lettets i the first array.

**Update**

There are two ways you can do this

First: Loop through every 5th index in the array (0,4,9,14... and so on), and change that letter in the **original** array.

```
for(int i=0; i < myArray.length; i+=5 ){
    myArray[i] = ...what to change to here..
}
```

Second: Copy **all** the values into a new array, and change every 5th element.

```
char[] newArray = new char[oldArray.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
        if(i % 5 == 0) {  //Every 5th element
            newArray[i] = ...what to change to here...;
        } else {
            newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
               }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I tried(forgot the '=' in my post, fixed now) but it didn't display the unchanged characters. Thanks though, overwriting the array works - although it still starts from the 1st character annoyingly.

Comment: Added an update with the two approaches one can make.

Comment: @heniv181 I fixed your code formatting, but please refrain from using curse words on this site in the future. You are expected to behave professionally on here.

Comment: @Magisch, thank you. Just frustrated at the poor and buggy formatting-editor for stackoverflow. Ponder on the irony of a site for programmers where you can't directly access the formating code. =D  Anyway, this is off-topic.

Comment: @heniv181 the only reason it didn't work right that time is because you used the numerated list. For some reason (probably a bug) code formatted after entries in a numerated list doesn't get displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to still operate on every character, but only shift the fifth character you could change your for loop to use a modulus:

```
for(int i=0; i < ptArray.length; i++){
     if( i%5 == 0 ){
         // Shifting the array code.
     }
     // Other character counting code.
}
```

Is this what you're trying to get at?

Comment: This is still giving me the same result as '(int i=0; i<ptArray.length; i+5)', "abcdefghij" becomes "ch" when shifted by 2, so it's shifting 'a' and 'f'. With that example I'm trying to shift 'e' and 'j' whilst displaying the unchanged characters also.

Comment: Did you copy the  unchanged chars to the  new array?

Comment: I did now, it's the same as 'i+=5' but overwriting the array keeps the unchanged characters. The first character remains it's starting point so it becomes every 6th letter instead though.